# JQuery toggleClass issue not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently started a project based on a dummy company I created for my portfolio site. I am having issues implementing a piece of jQuery code to toggle a class called hidden which will set the display of what the class is placed on to none. I am using this class to toggle the mobile navigations at certain media query breakpoints. However the toggleClass hidden is not working. Can any of you guys help?
Here is my site:
https://jorgeg1105.github.io/JG-Photography/

```js
//When the page loads, Fade in all divs with class hidden.
//Then Remove hidden class.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.hidden').fadeIn(2000).removeClass('hidden');
});

//Fade In all h3 with class hidden.
//Remove hidden class.
$('h3.hidden').fadeIn(3000).removeClass('hidden');

//Image Filter
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#mainnav ul li a").click(function (){
  var category = $(this).attr("class");

  if (category == "all" ){
   $("#imgcontainer img").addClass("hidden");
   setTimeout(function (){
    $("#imgcontainer img").removeClass("hidden");
   });
  }
  else {
   $("#imgcontainer img").addClass("hidden");
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("."+category).removeClass("hidden");
   });
  }
 });
});


//When burger is clicked. Mobile nav and mainnav are toggled.
$(".burger").on("click", function (){
 $("#mainnav").toggleClass("hidden");
 $(".mobilenav").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

#container {
 flex: 1 0 0;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

/*------------------------Classes to be added to the current active link on a page----------*/
.active {
 color: #766E6B;
}


/*--------------Side Navigation Styles--------------------*/
#sidenav {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 width: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 border-right: 6px solid #766E6B;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

#sidenav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
   justify-content: center;
}

#sidenav ul li:first-child {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
#sidenav ul li:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
  }

#sidenav a {
 padding: 20px;
 display: block;
}

#sidenav a:visited {
 color: white;
}

#sidenav a:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}



/*-------------Header Styles-------------------------------*/
header {
 padding: 40px 30px;
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
}

header h1, h3 {
 font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}

header h1 {
 font-size: 90px;
}

header h3 {
 font-size: 40px;
}

header a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 padding: 0 0 12px 0;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}

header a:hover {
 transition: color 1s;
 color: #766E6B;
}


.smalltxt {
 font-size: 12px;
}

.topnavitems {
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
}

/*------------------Main Navigation-----------------------*/

#mainnav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: black;
}


#mainnav li {
 margin-right: 5px;

}

#mainnav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#mainnav a:hover {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: grey;
}

/*--------------------ImgContainer Area------------------------*/

#imgcontainer {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
}

#imgcontainer img {
 flex: 1;
 width: 40vh;
 padding: 10px;
}

#imgcontainer img:hover {
 border: 2px solid black;
}
/*-----------------------Footer Styles---------------------*/

footer {
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-top: 1px solid grey;

}

footer ul {
 justify-content: center;
}

footer li {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.developer {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

/*-------------------Js Fade In class-------------------*/
.hidden {
 display: none;
}

/*-------------------Flexbox-----------------------*/
.col {
 flex: 1;
}

.row {
 display: flex;
}

/*----------------------Mobile Navigation------------------------*/

.mobilenav {
 background-color: black;
 justify-content: center;
 display: none;
}

.mobilenav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 margin: 0;
}

.mobilenav li {
 margin-right: 10px;

}

.mobilenav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 20px;
}

.mobilenav a:hover {
 background-color: grey;
}

.burger {
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 display: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.burger i {
 color: white;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

/*-----------------Mobile Footer------------------------------*/
.mobilefooter {
 display: none;
}

.mobilefooter a {
 color: black;
}

/*-----------Media Queries----------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
 #sidenav {
  display: none;
 }

 nav.mobilenav.row {

  display: none;
 }

 .mobilefooter {
  display: flex;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 930px){
 #imgcontainer img {
  width: 80vh;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
 header a {
  display: none;
 }

 .mobilenav {
  display: flex;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 header h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
 }

 header h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
 }

 #imgcontainer img {
  width: 95%;
 }

 #mainnav {
  display: block;
 }

 #mainnav ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
 }

 #mainnav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
 }

 .mobilenav {
  display: block;
 }

 .mobilenav ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;

 }

 .mobilenav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
 }

 .burger {
  display: block;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>| J&amp;D |</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!--Custom CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/styles.css">
 <!--Google Fonts-->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400i|Tangerine:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <nav id="sidenav" class="row">
  <ul class>
   <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
  <div id="container">
   <span class="burger"><a href="#" class="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
   <nav class="mobilenav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Questions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <header>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="index.html">
         <strong class="active">Gallery</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Our Work</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>About</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">D&amp;J Photography</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Questions</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Facts</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <h1>D&amp;J Photography</h1>
     <h3 class="hidden"><em>"Explore. Create. Inspire."</em></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Rates</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Your Investment</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Contact</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Get In Touch</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <span class="burger"><a href="#" class="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
    <nav id="mainnav">
   <ul class="row">
    <li><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="food">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="people">People</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="landmark">Landmarks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nature">Nature</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sneakers">Sneakers</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="imgcontainer">
   <a href="Images/Food/FriedChicken.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/FriedChicken.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/IcyMountains.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/IcyMountains.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/EiffelTower.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/EiffelTower.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/Girl.jpg"><img src="Images/People/GuyInTrees.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/GoldAndWhite.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/GoldAndWhite.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/ExoticDish.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/ExoticDish.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/VastLandscape.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/VastLandscape.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/LondonBridge.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/LondonBridge.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/GuyWithCap.jpg"><img src="Images/People/GuyWithCap.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Nike.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Nike.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/ShrimpRice.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/ShrimpRice.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/VeryGreenForest.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/VeryGreenForest.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/RomanColosseum.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/RomanColosseum.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/OlderMan.jpg"><img src="Images/People/OlderMan.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Vans.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Vans.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Yeezy.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Yeezy.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/SteakTacos.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/SteakTacos.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/MistyForest.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/MistyForest.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/GermanyCastle.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/GermanyCastle.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/LittleGirl.jpg"><img src="Images/People/LittleGirl.jpg" class="people"></a>
  </div>
  <footer>
   <ul class="row">
    <li><p class="smalltxt">J&amp;G Photography all rights reserved &copy; 2017</p></li>
    <li><p class="smalltxt">Designed and Developed by <strong><a href="http://jorgegoris.com/" class="developer">Jorge Goris</a></strong></p></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="mobilefooter row">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </footer>
 </div>
 <!--jQuery-->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <!--Font Awesome-->
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d579f311e9.js"></script>
   <!--Custom Js-->
   <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add Specific width to `li` `style="width:150px;text-align:center;"`  so flickering could be removed..

Comment: @Champ Decay I don't understand. I have a width 100% at the 600 px break point and my text is vertically aligned but what does this have to do with the jQuery?

Comment: Please only include [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Fate please define Not working

Comment: @Fate your second menu `All food ...` is flickering on hover. So use above css for li

Comment: @sagar Well when I add the class hidden (display: none;) to #mainnav and .mobilenav it should override their display and set the display to none correct? it is not doing that at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toggleClass hidden is not working because you have set the CSS rule in media queries that, if max-size is 600 or 740 then apply display block or flex properties that are overriding your hidden class property to make hidden class work you should do that:

```
.hidden{
 display: none !important;    
}
```

I have added !important here because you have already set in #mainnav the display property which has higher priority than any class(that doesn't have !important rule) and overrides another class properties.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I completely forgot about the !important property.

Comment: you're most welcome :). Sometimes minor mistakes can result what you not expected.

Comment: Yeah definitely. Also when I started this page I wasn't as fluent in Flex box and half way through the project I got better at it and did not go back and fix up the project. I will definitely get around to doing that. However, would you be able to tell me why my page has some scrolling to the side when I hit mobile phone width? I'm actually not too sure what is causing that.

Comment: I would suggest you that you should read more about flex property because it can create this unexpected result. Just remove your .row class and you would find solution for mobile view but then it would be incorrect on bigger screen. You must read about flex.